# How to add an appoinment/reminder in calendar uwp c#

Tags: uwp, outlook, microsoft-teams

I want to add appointment/meeting in calendar via uwp c# which i should see in outlook and all other apps.
I am using following code to add appointment but i could not see any appointments in outlook calendar

And I am not getting any notification also when the event start time comes.

'''

```
            var appCustomApptCalendar = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync("MyCalendar");



            // 3. create new Appointment 
            var appo = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();
            var date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
            var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
            var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second, timeZoneOffset);
            appo.StartTime = startTime;


            Logger.Info($"{startTime}");

            // appointment properties 
            appo.AllDay = true;
            appo.Subject = "Mein Termin";

            appo.Sensitivity = AppointmentSensitivity.Public;
            appo.Reminder = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
      

            Logger.Info("Saving app");
            await appCustomApptCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(appo);
```

'''

Comment: Hello, I tested your code and it works fine. After running the code, a calendar named "MyCalendar" appeared in the calendar application, and an all-day schedule was created today, and I got a notification reminder two minutes later. You can try to clear all calendars and schedules created by the application in the current calendar application, then re-run the project and test

Comment: Thanks for help Richard  . Actually i missed out installing "Mail & calendar" app in my PC. It is working now after installing app :)